# Check if player has a duplicate of a tool in roblox

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I am trying to check if a player has 2 Bloxy Colas in their backpack
and if there is 2 destroy the other one

I tried this code in a script but it didn't work

```
local tmpTable = {} -- store items names

for I,v in pairs(player.Backpack:GetChildren()) do --  loop through all items found
    if  tmpTable [v.Name] ~= nil then -- checks if item exists in the list
        print("a duplicate has been found") -- found item e.g. a duplicate
        v:Destroy() -- deletes tool 
    else
        tmpTable [v.Name]  = "BloxyCola"  -- we don't need to use the value we are only using the key
        print("item added to list") 
    end 
end
```

Comment: what do you mean with "didn't work"?  are there errors? or is the duplicate just not being removed? why is there a duplicate in the first place? you should not allow to add that item rather than remove it later. what is the output of that code? what does it print? how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: The duplicate not being removed. Nothing prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The duplicate not being removed. Nothing prints

You print something in both branches of your conditional statement. If there is nothing printed that means the loop does not run a single time. That means that `player.Backpack:GetChildren()` returns an empty table.

As `Instance:GetChildren()` will always return a table, seeing an empty table means that `Backpack` does not have any children.